# Input::file('fileInput') doesn't detect the File

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file, laravel

I have an individual html form for uploading photo on Laravel's blade and I am trying to post the image to the Controller.

The Html form looks like:

```
<form id="fileForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="fileInput" style="visibility: hidden"/>
    <input type="button" value="submit" id="ajaxSubmit" hidden />
</form>
```

And in (document.ready):

```
  jQuery('input[type=file]').change(function() {
       jQuery('#fileForm').submit();
  });


  jQuery('#fileForm').on('submit',(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();

       jQuery.ajax({
           url: '',
           type: 'POST',
           data: new FormData(jQuery(this)[0]),
           processData: false,
           success: function (data) {

           },
           complete: function() {

           }
        })
  }))
```

---

When I `dd(Input:all());` on the controller, it shows this and so on:

[image]

However, `dd(Input::file('fileInput))` returns null.

When I try `dd(Input::hasFile('fileForm'));` (which I feel it is not correct), it returns false

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#storing-uploaded-files

Comment: @Blake Both `dd($request->file('fileInput'));` and `dd($request->file('photo'));` returns null. What is the proper way to get the file?

Comment: Add `contentType: false` in your AJAX setting.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul Added it and tried both `$request->file('fileInput')` & `$request->file('photo')`. Still both returns null